# How to make sure an action completes before you continue

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

I am trying to close a UIView that's in one method from another method by calling it, The UIView closes fine but not until after all of the processes are finished in the current method.

I would like to know if there is a way to force the first thing to happen first (i.e. close UIviews) then continue the current method?

This is what my method looks like

```
- (void)selectDeselectAllPressed:(UIButton*)button {
    int id = button.tag;
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Updating" maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];
    [self displaySelected]; // removes current view so you can load hud will not be behind it

    if (id == 1) {
        [self selectAllD];
    } else if (id == 2) {
        [self deselectAllD];
    } else if (id == 3) {
        [self selectAllI];
    } else if (id == 4) {
        [self deselectAllI];
    }
}
```

As you can see what happens is this method is called when a button is pressed, I would like for the displaySelected method to do what it needs to do before any of the other methods are called?

Currently what happens when I debug this is displaySelected method is called the thread walks through that then continues to the if statement then after the method in the if statement has finished then displaySelected changes are made... it's so weird.

### Update

This is the method I am calling, there is an if statement which checks if the view is nil then it loads it otherwise it unloads it. At the point in the code which I am on the view is loaded so when I call it from selectDeselectAllPressed it's entering the else if part of the method to close the views. I have debugged and have seen the thread entering this point

```
- (void) displaySelected {

    if (allBackGroundView == nil) {

        // load view

        CGFloat fullHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
        CGFloat fullWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

        // draw background
        background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, fullHeight, fullWidth)];
        background.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        background.alpha = 0.6;
        [self.view addSubview:background];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(displaySelectedI)];
        gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
        [background addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

        allBackGroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(762.0, 43.0, 250.0, 220.0)];
        allBackGroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        allBackGroundView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
        allBackGroundView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
        [self.view addSubview:allBackGroundView];

        // set labeltitles
        selecteAllDFitLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 18.0, 200.0, 30.0)];
        selecteAllDFitLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        selecteAllDFitLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        selecteAllDFitLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        selecteAllDFitLabel.text = @"Select all Dfit:";
        [allBackGroundView addSubview:selecteAllDFitLabel];

        deselecteAllDFitLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 65.0, 200.0, 30.0)];
        deselecteAllDFitLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        deselecteAllDFitLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        deselecteAllDFitLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        deselecteAllDFitLabel.text = @"Deselect all Dfit:";
        [allBackGroundView addSubview:deselecteAllDFitLabel];

        selecteAllILabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 120.0, 200.0, 30.0)];
        selecteAllILabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        selecteAllILabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        selecteAllILabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        selecteAllILabel.text = @"Select all I:";
        [allBackGroundView addSubview:selecteAllILabel];

        deselecteAllILabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 170.0, 200.0, 30.0)];
        deselecteAllILabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        deselecteAllILabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        deselecteAllILabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        deselecteAllILabel.text = @"Deselect all I:";
        [allBackGroundView addSubview:deselecteAllILabel];

        UIImage* okImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"OK.png"];
        UIImage* noImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"No.png"];

        selecteAllDFitButton =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        selecteAllDFitButton.tag = 1; // so I know what action to perform when i call selectDeselectAllPressed
        [selecteAllDFitButton addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(selectDeselectAllPressed:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        selecteAllDFitButton.frame = CGRectMake(200.0, 12.0, 40.0, 40.0);
        [selecteAllDFitButton setImage:okImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [allBackGroundView addSubview:selecteAllDFitButton];

        deselecteAllDFitButton =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        deselecteAllDFitButton.tag = 2;
        [deselecteAllDFitButton addTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(selectDeselectAllPressed:)
                         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        deselecteAllDFitButton.frame = CGRectMake(200.0, 62.0, 40.0, 40.0);
        [deselecteAllDFitButton setImage:noImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [allBackGroundView addSubview:deselecteAllDFitButton];

        selecteAllIButton =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        selecteAllIButton.tag = 3;
        [selecteAllIButton addTarget:self
                                     action:@selector(selectDeselectAllPressed:)
                           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        selecteAllIButton.frame = CGRectMake(200.0, 112.0, 40.0, 40.0);
        [selecteAllIButton setImage:okImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [allBackGroundView addSubview:selecteAllIButton];

        deselecteAllIButton =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        deselecteAllIButton.tag = 4;
        [deselecteAllIButton addTarget:self
                                    action:@selector(selectDeselectAllPressed:)
                          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        deselecteAllIButton.frame = CGRectMake(200.0, 162.0, 40.0, 40.0);
        [deselecteAllIButton setImage:noImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [allBackGroundView addSubview:deselecteAllIButton];


    }
    else {
        [allBackGroundView removeFromSuperview];
        [background removeFromSuperview];
        allBackGroundView = nil;
        background = nil;

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used multi-threading inside `displaySelected` ?

Comment: No, Im not sure how to do that.

Comment: Then you are OK... can you post code from `displaySelected` ?

Comment: you should implement the delegate pattern and do the logic stuff in a delegate method. alternately you could use blocks.

Comment: Block-based API is much prefered, as it ties nicely with the UIKit block-based animation API. See my answer for a proposal.

Comment: @Roshan I have posted the method it calls.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a block-based API, and pass a block to `displaySelected`.

Consider:

```
- (void)selectDeselectAllPressed:(UIButton*)button {
    int id = button.tag;
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Updating" maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];
    [self displaySelectedCompletionBlock: ^ (BOOL completed) {
        if(!completed) { return; }

        if (id == 1) {
            [self selectAllD];
        } else if (id == 2) {
            [self deselectAllD];
        } else if (id == 3) {
            [self selectAllI];
        } else if (id == 4) {
            [self deselectAllI];
        }
    }]; // removes current view so you can load hud will not be behind it
}
```

And in `displaySelectedCompletionBlock:`:

```
- (void)displaySelectedCompletionBlock:(void(^)(BOOL))completionBlock
{
    //Setup animations.
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations: ^ { /* Do animations here. */ } completion:[completionBlock copy]];
}
```

This is a simplification, but should give you an idea how to proceed.

Comment: I have updated my code.. however I am getting this error **Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(BOOL)' to parameter of type 'void (^)()'**

Comment: `- (void)displaySelectedCompletionBlock:(void(^)(BOOL))completionBlock`